# In MS PowerPoint: Is there any possibility to delete all slides that are hidden?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

I have a PowerPoint presentation that has several hidden slides and I want to know if there is any possibility to delete all the hidden slides without having to do it one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim x as Long
For x = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count to 1 Step -1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(x)
       If .SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True Then
          .Delete
       End If
    End with
Next
```